# What's the difference between the /usr/bin/gcc and /Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am recently working on cross compile a library to arm7 architecture on a OSX machine(10.9). I got some instructions online saying I must reset all the compilers and preprocessors to the ones that hides inside XCode. I assume there must be some difference between the ones in Xcode and the ones installed in command line tools.

I did a gcc --version to both ones and I saw the description is different. Beside this one, is there any other difference on those two. Is there any reference on this topic talking about the two different gcc.

Thanks

Comment: Totally impossible to tell without knowing more about your system.

Comment: Sorry, I will add more information.

Comment: *I did a gcc --version to both ones and I saw the description is different. Beside this one ...* `--version` lists all the options used when generating the compiler and the source version: these are all the differences (except for the file location). Your question sounds like *Beside the colour, what's the difference between a green and a red T-shirt?*

Comment: Mine are both identical, you might try re-installing the command line tools: "xcode-select --install" and re-checking the versions. Mine: Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 0):

depends: both could be different.

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

could be either installed with an old Xcode or a custom installer, the version will say if it has been patched by apple.

The one in the Xcode's bundle is the current one for that version of Xcode, and changes with basically every Xcode update, and will get used for xcodebuild command, if xcode-select has that version selected, you can install the Xcode one from inside of the Xcode preferences.